# Selenium - Can't access page object model properties

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, pageobjects, webautomation

I'm using the Boni Garcia 'webdrivermanager'.
https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/README.md

**My issue**:
I'm not able to 'get' my initialized driver properties from '*BaseSwag*' to 'home.page' in order to launch Chrome and go to the desired URL. Here is my set up as follows. What can I do to fix this?

**src/main/java/swaglogin/BaseSwag**

```
package swaggerLogin;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.managers.ChromeDriverManager;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.managers.FirefoxDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class BaseSwag {

  public WebDriver driver;
  public Properties prop;

  public WebDriverManager initializeDriver() throws IOException {
    // Create global property file
    prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
        "//Users/rad/WebTest/src/main/resources/data.properties");

    prop.load(fis);
    String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
    System.out.println(browserName);

    if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
      WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (browserName.equals("firefox")) {
      WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    return driver;
  }
}
```

**resources/data.properties**

```
url = http://qaclickacademy.com/
apiKey = 1234563333random
browser = chrome
```

**test/java/home.page**

```
package home.page;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import swaggerLogin.BaseSwag;

public class SwaggerLoginDev extends BaseSwag {

  @BeforeTest

  public void initialize() throws IOException {
    driver = initializeDriver();
    driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));

  }

}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Error:(32, 12) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method driver()
  location: class resources.Base
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `driver` variable should be an instance of `WebDriver`, not `WebDriverManager`.

You can consider WebDriverManager as utility class, that only manage (download, setup, etc...) your drivers for different browsers. Once you call `.setup()` method for the desired type of browser, you can create an instance of it:

```java
public class BaseSwag {

  public WebDriver driver;
  public Properties prop;

  public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException {
    // Create global property file
    prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
        "//Users/rad/WebTest/src/main/resources/data.properties");

    prop.load(fis);
    String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
    System.out.println(browserName);

    if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
      WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (browserName.equals("firefox")) {
      WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    return driver;
  }
}
```

Now, you should be able to call `.get(...)` method on your driver.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick reply.

After pasting the provided answer, I get the following 'Cannot resolve symbol'. Please see the edits I made to 'BaseSwag'. (added comment)

Comment: @FeatherDuster, then update your imports: `import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver`

Comment: I definitely forgot about my dependency there. But now I have another issue regarding 'return driver;'  it's saying "Method call expected", but not sure what I'm missing. If it makes it easier, I through it into GitHub for your convenience. [Sample_Driver_Test](https://github.com/intuitive86/Sample_Driver_Test)

Comment: Added stack trace above

Comment: I've fixed your issue (and couple of other), will create a PR in a couple of minutes

Comment: Thank you, can't wait to see the changes and where I messed up.

Comment: Could you please check my PR?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214096/discussion-between-yevhen-danchenko-and-featherduster).